# Git heads messed up?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

Under branch `dev`, when I run

```
git status
```

I get

```
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'hub/dev'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I run

```
git remote show hub
```

I get

```
* remote hub   
  Fetch URL: ssh://user@user.com/home/user/private/repos/user_hub.git
  Push  URL: ssh://user@user.com/home/user/private/repos/user_hub.git   

  HEAD branch: master   
  Remote branches:
            dev        tracked
            master     tracked
            userModule tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
            dev    merges with remote dev
            master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
            dev        pushes to dev        (up to date)
            master     pushes to master     (up to date)
            userModule pushes to userModule (up to date)
```

I didn't expect to get `HEAD branch: master`. What's wrong?

## Problem / Question

Under `dev`, when I run `git push`, it pushes to the `hub/master`, whereas it should be pushed to `hub/dev`. How can I fix this, so that, when we are on branch `dev`, it pushes to the `hub/dev` instead?

### Update

According to some comments, the configuration above seems correct.

See my `post-update` hook below; could the problem be caused by it?

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "**** Pulling changes... [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo

case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/dev'*)
cd /home/user/www/dev/ || exit
        unset GIT_DIR
        git pull hub dev
        echo
        echo "Dev was pulled"
        echo
        ;;
esac

case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/master'*)
        cd /home/user/www/www/ || exit
        unset GIT_DIR
        git fetch hub && git reset --hard hub/master
        echo
        echo "Master was reset to reflect bare changes. PRAY THE LORD!"
        echo
        ;;
esac

exec git-update-server-info
```

Here's the **git config**:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "hub"]
        url = ssh://user@user.com/home/user/private/repos/user_hub.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hub/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = hub
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "dev"]
        remote = hub
        merge = refs/heads/dev
[merge]
        renameLimit = 999999
```

**Update 2:**
The issue seems to be solved, but as far as I can tell, I did nothing to "fix" it. :s Still, if someone cares to clarify if something is wrong, or why this could be a problem, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: `HEAD branch: master` is just fine. Look at the [example here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Inspecting-a-Remote)

Comment: So, what is the question here?

Comment: I've updated the question, by adding more information, and to clarify the question/difficulty that I'm having.

Comment: What can be done for diagnostics:

Push to some other remote. This will show, if the problem is on the local side.

Pull from the current remote to a new repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of git are you using?
Prior to git v2.0 `git push` will push **all** your branches in no origin/branch name supplied !!!

Read the first paragraph of the release notes:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

> When "git push [$there]" does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   "matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

As you described in your Question - your dev status is clean but when you push it pushes to master. sounds like you had some un-pushed commits in master so `git push` simply pushed master as well.

Comment: For information, in a (now deleted) comment, the OP wrote that s/he uses Git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3).

Comment: It makes all the sense.Thank you so much for your time here.